# Regular expressions are not all understood by "LIKE" . Have I to modify them ? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

### **On SQL Server Management Studio**

Regular expressions are not all understood by "LIKE" . 
I got regular expressions in a table where "{" and "|" give me troubles. 
Have I to modify them ?

Case is I have a ProductId and ProductIdFormat :

```
1. ProductId
 C10PA0024
 03555521

2. ProductIdFormat
 [0-9]{8}|[0-9]{7}|[c-dC-D][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

SELECT ProductId
FROM   Company
WHERE  ProductId like ProductIdFormat
```

...does not return anything :'(

The only way I found is to transform the Regular Expression with sql query like :

```
replicate(substring('[0-9]{4}', 1, charindex(']', '[0-9]{4}')), substring('[0-9]{4}', charindex('{', '[0-9]{4}') + 1, charindex('}', '[0-9]{4}') - (1 + charindex('{', '[0-9]{4}'))))
```

"Simple" line but much more difficult with the one shown higher and all others you can't see :/

---

Comment: Well yeah... `LIKE` is not documented as supporting regular expressions. What made you think it would support them? Most regexes cannot be translated to `LIKE` patterns at all. What's the most complicated regex that you need to get working?

Comment: Bad news: `LIKE` does not use regular expressions.  You could use .net integration features of SQL server to process the regular expression (without LIKE). However that sounds like WAY MORE work than just translating your regex to SQL LIKE syntax.

Comment: I didn't think it supports it. I just arrive on a project where i have to compare 2 columns : one with RegExp, one with Characters to compare with ...

Comment: @CestDede Where in the documentation says SQL Server `LIKE` ever support Regular Expression??

Comment: Please just read my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussing with developpers led me to use CLR integration that allow me to use RegEx.Match function to make SQL Server understand every Regular Expressions ... SQL Manager didn't want to use it.
Thou I created a function to compare directly the numbers with regular expressions.

In the end, I created a function which compare a number to the format whatever the "format" of the format ^^ :

```
            USE [RequetesHarmonie]
            GO
            /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[RegExpLike]    Script Date: 8/13/2018 5:08:06 PM ******/
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO
            -- Test pour la correspondance RegExp d'un champ
            --/****************************************************************************/
            -- exemple : RegExpLike(085zer, '[0-9a-zA-Z]{5}|[0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z]') => VRAI         ou FAUX

            -- ==============================================
            --La fonction 'like' est incapable de lire une expression reguliere de la forme ([ab][cd]) à cause des parenthese
            --La fonction 'like' prend les '|' comme caractère invisible : Il faut donc créer une fonction qui sépare deux formats. 
            --    Le fait de trouver un '|' dans un format, càd dans des [], n'impacte en rien la fonction
            -- ==============================================


            ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RegExpLike](@NB VARCHAR (8000), @FORMATNB VARCHAR (8000))

            RETURNS VARCHAR (8000)
            AS 
            BEGIN 
            -- effets de bord
               IF @FORMATNB IS NULL
                  RETURN 'VRAI'
               IF LEN(@FORMATNB) = 0
                  RETURN 'VRAI'
               IF @NB IS NULL
                  RETURN 'FAUX'
               IF LEN(@NB) = 0
                  RETURN 'FAUX'
            -- initialisation
               DECLARE  @OUT VARCHAR(8000)
               DECLARE  @PROC VARCHAR(8000)
                            SET @PROC = ''
               DECLARE @F VARCHAR(8000)
               DECLARE  @IMAX VARCHAR(8000)
                            SET @IMAX = LEN(@FORMATNB)-LEN(REPLACE(@FORMATNB,'|[','['))
               DECLARE  @I INTEGER
                            SET @I = 0
               DECLARE @FORMATNB1 VARCHAR(8000)
               DECLARE @FORMATNB2 VARCHAR(8000)
               DECLARE @FORMATNB3 VARCHAR(8000)
            -- Définition des différents formats
            BEGIN
                If @IMAX = 0
                    set @FORMATNB1 = ''
                    set @FORMATNB2 = ''
                    set @FORMATNB3 = ''
            If @IMAX = 1
                    set @FORMATNB1 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
                    set @FORMATNB2 = ''
                    set @FORMATNB3 = ''
            If @IMAX = 2
                    set @FORMATNB1 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
                    set @FORMATNB2 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
                    set @FORMATNB3 = ''
            If @IMAX = 3
                    set @FORMATNB1 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
                    set @FORMATNB2 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
                    set @FORMATNB3 = substring(@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB, Charindex( '|[' ,@FORMATNB) + 1) + 1) + 1 ,LEN(@FORMATNB))
            If @IMAX > 3 
                    RETURN 'FAUX'

                end 

                --Comparaison des formats
                  While @I <= @IMAX
               BEGIN
                     if @I = 0 and @FORMATNB not like '%}%'
                        set @F = @FORMATNB

                    else IF @I = 0 and @FORMATNB like '%}%'
                        set @F =  replicate(substring(@FORMATNB,
                            charindex('[', @FORMATNB),
                            charindex(']{', @FORMATNB) - charindex('[', @FORMATNB) + 1), 
                                substring( @FORMATNB, 
                            charindex('{', @FORMATNB) + 1, 
                            charindex('}', @FORMATNB) - charindex('{', @FORMATNB) - 1)
                                            )


                    else if @I = 1 and @FormatNb1 not like '%}%'
                        set @F = @FormatNb1

                    else if @I = 1 and @FormatNb1 like '%}%'
                        set @F = replicate(substring(@FormatNb1,
                            charindex('[', @FormatNb1),
                            charindex(']{', @FormatNb1) - charindex('[', @FormatNb1) + 1), 
                                substring( @FormatNb1, 
                            charindex('{', @FormatNb1) + 1, 
                            charindex('}', @FormatNb1) - charindex('{', @FormatNb1) - 1)
                                            )


                    else if @I = 2  and @FormatNb2 not like '%}%'
                        set @F = @FormatNb2

                    else if @I = 2  and @FORMATNB2 like '%}%'
                        set @F = replicate(substring(@FormatNb2,
                            charindex('[', @FormatNb2),
                            charindex(']{', @FormatNb2) - charindex('[', @FormatNb2) + 1), 
                                substring( @FormatNb2, 
                            charindex('{', @FormatNb2) + 1, 
                            charindex('}', @FormatNb2) - charindex('{', @FormatNb2) - 1)
                                            )

                    else if @I = 3 and @FormatNb3 not like '%}%'
                        set @F = @FormatNb3

                    else if @I = 3 and @FormatNb3 like '%}%'
                        set @F = replicate(substring(@FormatNb3,
                            charindex('[', @FormatNb3),
                            charindex(']{', @FormatNb3) - charindex('[', @FormatNb3) + 1), 
                                substring( @FormatNb3, 
                            charindex('{', @FormatNb3) + 1, 
                            charindex('}', @FormatNb3) - charindex('{', @FormatNb3) - 1)
                                            )

                        IF @NB like @F
                             SET @PROC = @PROC + 'VRAI'
                        else SET @PROC = @PROC + 'FAUX' 

                        SET @I = @I + 1
                END 

                BEGIN
                    If @PROC like '%VRAI%' 
                            set @OUT = 'VRAI'
                    else    set @OUT = 'FAUX'
                    end
                    return @OUT
                    end
```